# Pandas reindexing data frame issue

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following data frame,

```
         A       B
0  1986-87  232131
1  1987-88  564564
2  1988-89  123125
               ...
```

And so on.

I'm trying to reindex, with `<myFrame>.set_index('A')`, so that I get

```
                B
  1986-87  232131
  1987-88  564564
  1988-89  123125
```

but I keep getting this instead:

```
               B
       A       
 1986-87  232131
 1987-88  564564
 1988-89  123125
```

and its annoying as heck cause I tried the other reindexing methods. I'm not sure what the `A` is actually representing because it doesn't appear in `<myFrame>.columns` or `<myFrame>.index` and doing `<myFrame>['B'][0]` gives me `232131`, so what is `A` in this reindexed data frame and how can I index correctly from the beginning or get rid of this strange `A` in the incorrectly reindex data frame.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to reset the name/names attribute of the index:

```
df.index.names = [None]
```

Example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B']).set_index('A')

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   B
A   
1  2
3  4

In [13]: df.index.names = [None]

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   B
1  2
3  4
```

*The names describe the index, and give some meaning to the index, and also distinguishes between different levels in the index (in a MultiIndex).*

As @DSM points out, do so at your own peril, this loses info if you want to reset_index back:

```
In [15]: df.reset_index() # col_fill=['A', 'B'])
Out[15]: 
   index  B
0      1  2
1      3  4
```

However, you can col_fill in the names manually:

```
In [16]: df.reset_index(col_fill=['A'])
Out[16]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! But can you elaborate a little bit more on why I need to reset the names attribute? What was the `A` acting as? EDIT: much appreciated.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian certainly names makes more sense for MultiIndex, I also find them useful for single level index too (though I agree table is a little ugly).

Comment: The information has to be preserved *somewhere*, or `.set_index("A").reset_index()` wouldn't get you back where you started..

Answer (score 10):

I think your main problem is that you need to actually save the result of `set_index`, or use `inplace=True`, for the index to be set:

```
# Either
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
# Or:
# df = df.set_index('A')
```

The output you were seeing was correct, it was a dataframe indexed by A, but you just hadn't stored it in a variable. Once you have stored it, things should work like you expect:

```
df.index
Out[6]: Index([u'1986-87', u'1987-88', u'1988-89'], dtype=object)

df.loc[u'1987-88']
Out[8]: 
B    564564
Name: 1987-88, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Didn't work how? It should work for all the indexing operations you need, it's just that index has a name, and is printed accordingly.

Comment: it didn't insofar as I was still getting my third data frame example. Andy's answer gets me the desired output.

Comment: Thank you! I was so blind :)

Answer (score -2):

I have a dataframe that is generated from appending multiple dataframe together into a long list. As shown in figure, the default index is a loop between 0 ~ 7 because each original df has this index. The total row number is 240. So how can reindex the new df into 0~239 instead of 30 x 0~7.

I tried `df.reset_index(drop=True)`, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried:`df.reindex(np.arange(240))` but it returned error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

[image]